# how to used css @media in django?

Tags: css, django

I am creating a Django project with the dynamic screen using CSS @media but it does not work.

```
....
@media screen and (max-width: 500px)
....
```

The HTML will take either one of them or not at all. Or do we have to do it in a different way in Django?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user9911049,

If you need to add dynamic **css** based on media screen according to the template file.

You may use the following technique. Just create a CSS block before  i.e body tag. In the base template file in your templates/base.html

```
  {% block css %}

  {% block %}
```

And add your **dynamic css within the css block** in your template file.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block css %}
  <style>
  @media screen and (max-width: 500px)
  </style>
{% block %}
```

Comment: I try it out and only the css in the media is working. Others are ok but the font size is not changing

Comment: @user9911049, May be you need to use the !important for create any effect try to use !important for font-size. Actually this is **css issue**. But you may try.

Comment: Thank you...It worked now without the css !important. It was just some naming problem